# How harmful is Saturn's magnetic field for human life?

Tags: jupiter, magnetic-field, saturn, radiation, astrobiology

AFAIK, Jupiter has the strongest magnetic field in the solar system, and it's so powerful that I've been told humans only could survive the radiation generated by it in its mooon Callisto, with proper protection.

But how about Saturn? Saturn has the second strongest magnetic field in the solar system. Which moons of Saturn could men survive from the radiation generated by the planet's magnetic field in?

Comment: Interesting! I will look more into this.

Comment: "...could men survive from the radiation..." This does not sound like a question about *Astronomy*. You can ask about the type and intensity of charged particles here, but I think the part of the question about survivability should be asked separately in Space Exploration SE. Another option is to move the whole question there, but it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: hmmmm.. when astronomers look for exoplanets in the habitable zone, planets which could have life, it's more or less of the same, they are dealing with Astronomy and Biology and Physics aspects.

Comment: BTW, it's not like I dont have doubts if it should be here now, but there is also an Astrobiology tag here which is about "the origins, early evolution, distribution, and future of life in the universe"

Comment: It's not exactly the magnetic field that's the problem, it's the charged, fast moving particles in the Jupiter's enormous magnetosphere.   Standing on the surface of (pick your Galilean moon), the magnetic field is harmless to us but the protons, electrons, alpha particles and occasional bit of antimatter are harmful.

Comment: @Pablo I think this is a really interesting topic, I just think you have several questions here. Humans (or similar) can't live on Saturn, it doesn't have a surface, or oxygen. Terrestrial exoplanets would not likely have a magnetic field as strong as Jupiter or Saturn, and an atmosphere would tend to block radiation trapped in the magnetic field anyway. However, moons like Titan are large enough to have an atmosphere, and still experience the magnetic field from the planet to some extent. So maybe you can think more about either Saturn-like planets closer to their sun, or water/ice moons.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere_of_Saturn) says that "The saturnian radiation belts are generally much weaker than those of Jupiter" mostly due to the rings and other orbiting bodies absorbing the ions, I think. I have't yet found anything quantitative though